# jButton responds only to second click

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton

This post seems to be duplicated, but I not understand the solution in the same. I can not understand why the jbutton only works when I click two times.

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String address = jTextField1.getText();  
     Socket sock = null;
        try {
            InetAddress addr;
            sock = new Socket(address, 80);
            addr = sock.getInetAddress();
            sock.close();
            jLabel2.setText("Status: Online"); 
        } catch (IOException ex) {
             jLabel2.setText("Status: Offline");
        }      
    }
}); 
}
```

Comment: Remove `jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {` (and the trailing `}`, the `ActionListener` is already registered to the button though netbeans form editor - although I'd re-register the event to use an `ActionListener` rather then a `MouseListener`

Comment: understood @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jButton1MouseClicked` would suggest that a `MouseListener` is already registered against the button through Netbeans.

Remove the registration of the `ActionListener` from with the `jButton1MouseClicked` handler...

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    String address = jTextField1.getText();  
    Socket sock = null;
    try {
        InetAddress addr;
        sock = new Socket(address, 80);
        addr = sock.getInetAddress();
        sock.close();
        jLabel2.setText("Status: Online"); 
    } catch (IOException ex) {
         jLabel2.setText("Status: Offline");
    }      
}
```

Having said that, go back into Netbeans form editor and remove the `mouseClicked` handler associated with the button and either add the `ActionListener` manually (after the call to `initComponents`) or a "action" handler through the Netbeans form editor

The reason been is, buttons can be actioned through other means, like the keyboard